# Where did the icon come from?

Tags: cocoa, macos

Is there a unix tool to which I can pass a file and have it tell me where the icon for the file is coming from?

What I am looking for is something like this:

$WhoProvidedIcon /Path/To/file.myex

UTI: com.myapplication.document

PLIST: /path/to/myapplication.app/Contents/Info.plist

ICON: /path/to/myapplication.app/Contents/Resources/BaseDoc.icns

Comment: The reason I need this is purely for debugging purposes. 

An icon is being assigned to a file that shouldn't be assigned and it would be helpful to know where the icon is coming from exactly.

Comment: I can get part of the answer with the code:

NSString* uti = [ws typeOfFile:@"/Users/egorr/Desktop/file.vwx" error:&error]; 
NSLog( @"UTI: %@", uti );

What I am still unsure of is how to get the path to the icon for the file.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you have _A_ file with conflicting icons, or loads of files of varying extensions? Documents get their icons assigned by Finder.app based on information and icons it collects from the installed apps on the system. If your goal is to alter all the VectorWorks files you should write code to gather all .vwx files and then use `setIcon: forFile: options:` on all the files, writing code to alter the contents of other applications is a bit fishy.

Comment: I would like a tool that would tell me from where a files icon is coming. I have a file that is showing one can when it should be showing another and believe it would be useful if I had a tool that would tell from where that icon is coming. This should all be defined by the info.plist for the application and, as near as I can tell, it is all correct....yet, the wrong icon is showing up. This only seems to affect one particular machine at the moment and I cannot reproduce it on my machine.

Comment: It might actually be your launch services database, check out http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20031215144430486 for instructions on rebuilding it.

Comment: Yes, but I need to also try to understand how it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three different place from which the OS will provide the icon.

In one situation, NSWorkspace can be used to help identify the location:

```
NSString* uti = [ws typeOfFile:@"/Users/egorr/Desktop/file.vwx" error:&error];
NSLog( @"UTI: %@", uti );
NSLog( @"UTI localized description: %@", [ws localizedDescriptionForType:uti] );
NSLog( @"UTI error description: %@",[error localizedDescription] );
NSURL* utiDeclarationURL = (NSURL*)UTTypeCopyDeclaringBundleURL( (CFStringRef)uti );
NSLog( @"UTI declaration URL: %@", utiDeclarationURL );
NSDictionary* utiDeclaration = (NSDictionary*)UTTypeCopyDeclaration( (CFStringRef)uti );
NSLog( @"UTI declaration: %@", utiDeclaration );
```

This won't quite get the path to the icon, but it will get one the application from which the declaration came for the UTI.

An icon might also be supplied from a Quick Look plugin and output from qlmanage can be used to determine if this is the case.

A user can, in Finder's Get Info window, set the application they prefer for all files of a given "type". One can set text file types to always open in TextMate, for example. TextMate the app provides custom file icons for all the file types it can save in. After making this change in Finder's get info windows, all files of that type will have an icon that has been provided by TextMate and registered with a UTI. To determine whether this is the case, one would need to look at the launch services database - lsregister -dump

Answer (score 2):

Icons for most applications on Mac OSX are stored within the app bundle themselves. If you right click on the .app and then select `Show Package Contents` then go to `Contents -> Resources` you should see the icon in there.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't clear enough. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific tools that provide this information. However, it sounds like you have overlapping extensions. If Finder.app is showing an icon for a file then you should be able to just look in the info window for the file and see what application is listed to open the document by default. Then look at the .plist file for that application to see if it is using your extension. The info window should also say what kind of document it is which could be useful if the application that is supplying the icon has been deleted, or otherwise not listed as the default application.

Comment: It is not that simple. There are multiple versions of the same application all of whom are claiming the same extension. It is possible that one of them has become corrupted, but I don't think the finder is going to tell me which one, if that is indeed the case. Hence, the potential need for a tool to tell me from where the finder has actually obtained the icon for the file.